# Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin error after upgrading spring_cloud.version to 2021.0.0

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am attempting to update the spring cloud dependency from spring_cloud.version=2020.0.3
to spring_cloud.version=2021.0.0.

This causes an error when running the gradle build due to the following error

```
> Task :dispute-visa:compileKotlin FAILED
e: /Users/my.name/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-function-context/3.2.1/3b1b11733424ba90bd0b030a924e6b7deb2ff845/spring-cloud-function-context-3.2.1.jar!/META-INF/spring-cloud-function-context.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.2.

/Users/my.name/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-function-context/3.2.1/3b1b11733424ba90bd0b030a924e6b7deb2ff845/spring-cloud-function-context-3.2.1.jar!/META-INF/spring-cloud-function-context.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.2.
```

The spring cloud dependency is `implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka")`

If this spring cloud dependency is removed then the build works.
If the spring cloud dependency is replaced with another spring cloud dependency then the build will fail with a similar error.

These are the relevent versions of other parts

```
kotlin.version=1.5.32
spring_boot.version=2.5.6
```

I have tried changing kotlin version and spring boot version with no effect.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Spring cloud 2021.0 is not compatible with boot 2.5.x, only boot 2.6.x

Comment: thanks for the help! I did try upgrading to 2.6.4 sadly it had no effect

Comment: What version of Gradle do you use?

Comment: thanks @МихаилНафталь my gradle is 
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip

Comment: That's strange. Gradle 7.2+ is bundled with Kotlin 1.5+ (which [should work fine with 1.6](https://blog.mbonnin.net/kotlin-compatibility-quicksheet)), so the question is why it expects Kotlin 1.4.2. Does it really use 7.2 (check with `gradlew --version`). Are you sure, you are running Gradle build with `gradlew`, not locally installed `gradle`, which could have a different version? Also, try to search for the "1.4.2" string in your project - maybe this version of Kotlin is defined for some subproject?

Comment: Any chance you can provide a [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that the issue can be reproduced on our end?

Comment: ------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-08-17 09:59:03 UTC
Revision:     a773786b58bb28710e3dc96c4d1a7063628952ad

Kotlin:       1.5.21
Groovy:       3.0.8
JVM:          11.0.12 (Homebrew 11.0.12+0)
OS:           Mac OS X 12.0.1 x86_64
@МихаилНафталь

Comment: @sobychacko it would be really nice to be able to do an MCRE but I am working on a big project with multiple repos that are imported as libs. I am well aware that it is probably a clash between some property or dependency, but just don't know what to check after the obvious.
These libs is also use spring cloud and spring boot. One of the repo's is running Hoxton.SR12 for example. Due to the fact it is a common lib it is not feasible to update this repo. This may have something to do with the problem, but we have had different versions of spring across repo's many times with no problems.